# How do open python NLTK downloader

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to download all the nltk packages :

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

But the GUI don't open.
This is what appears instead :

```
NLTK Downloader
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    d) Download   l) List    u) Update   c) Config   h) Help   q) Quit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I type `d` I can see the list of available packages but I'm not offered to download them.

How can I open the GUI, or how can I download them all from the console ? Thanks.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://www.nltk.org/data.html)? Especially the section on command-line installation and/or manual installation could prove useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
nltk.download('all')
```

this will download all the data and no need to download individually.